# Issues with php/javascript regarding value

Tags: javascript, php

So I have this function that creates textareas depending on the month. So if it is March, then 31 textareas, April, then 30 textareas and so on. When the user clicks on one textarea and then the submit button, the value of the textarea should be submitted to the db. So if the user marks 2018-02-04, then that date should be inserted into the db. But, my problem right now is that the only value that is submitted is the last date of each month. Not sure why, and dont know how to solve it. Think it might be something with IDs. Or that I need to send the value in as an array. But not sure on how to do it.

Functions:

```
var showDate = new Date();
var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June",
              "July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuseday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];


function drawTable(forDate) {
    var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
    var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
    var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
            var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);

            var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
            textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
            //textarea.setAttribute("id", some_value); does not work
            newRow.appendChild(textarea);
            textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
            textarea.setAttribute("day",  newdate + "-" + day1 )
            textarea.innerHTML = newdate + "-" + day1;
            cellsToDraw--;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable(showDate );
};

function next() {
    if (showDate.getMonth() == 11) {
        showDate.setMonth( 0 );
        showDate.setFullYear( showDate.getFullYear()+1 );
    } else {
        showDate.setMonth( showDate.getMonth()+1 );
    }
    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable( showDate );
}
```

html:

```
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
      <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse";>
         <br>
         <input id="btn"  type="submit" name="" value="Send">
       </form>
```

php:

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
$day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day']);

$stmt = "INSERT INTO table (day) VALUES('$day')";
if(empty($day)){
  $_SESSION['error'] = "Please fill in required fields";

  header('Location: index.php', true, 303);
  exit();
} else {
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $stmt)) {
    header('Location: index.php', true, 303);
        exit;
  }else {
    $error= "Error: " .mysqli_error($conn);
    echo "$error";

  }
}

?>
```

My test php:

```
$days = $_request['day'];
    $error = array();
    foreach ($days as $day) {
    $day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $day);
        if (empty($day)) {
        $error[] = array(
            'day' => $day,
            'error' => 'day was empty'
        );
    }
        else if (
        !mysqli_query(
            $conn,
            "INSERT INTO table (day) VALUES('$day)')"
        )
    ) {
        $error[] = array(
            'day' => $day,
            'error' => mysqli_error($conn)
        );
    }
}

if (count($error)) {
    print_r($error);
}

header('Location: index.php', true, 303);
```

All help is appriciated! :)

Comment: Those form elements to submit need `name` attribute, without name the element's value is not submitted.

Comment: @Teemu not sure I quite understand what you mean. The name of the textareas are "day"

Comment: "Or that I need to send the value in as an array".  This.  Research submitting and handling input arrays.

Comment: Hmm... one name, one textarea, use `day[]` as the name, that way you'll get an array of textareas.

Comment: @Teemu hmm.. yes I was thinking about that. But not sure how the php would look like then

Comment: @PatrickQ thanks! I tried to do that. SOF was my las solution hahah not sure how to take in everything that I find online

Comment: If you've tried, then show your attempt and describe the results. What you have above shows no indication of an attempt to do this.

Comment: @PatrickQ added my tests, but as I stated before, it did not work.. all help is appriciated!

Comment: Okay, but did you actually name the input elements as arrays in the HTML? Also, as in your first example, it is always `$_REQUEST`, not `$_request` (as in your second example).  And you should not inject request variables directly into SQL statements.  It is not safe.  You should learn to use prepared statements and bound variables.

Comment: @PatrickQ yes I did! I will look in to that a bit later, I want to figure out this issue first

Answer (score 0):

**As I understood, you want to send date selected by user to server but last date of month is getting submitted right now. If this is your purpose and issue respectively then see it**

ON JSFIDDLE.NET

https://jsfiddle.net/wyn1cd5b/1/

STACKOVERFLOW SNIPPET

```js
function drawTable(forDate) {

  var table = document.getElementById('table')

  var year = forDate.getFullYear()
  var month = forDate.getMonth() + 1

  document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = months[month - 1]

  table.innerHTML = ''

  var daysInMonth = new Date(year, month, 0).getDate()

  for (i = 1; i <= daysInMonth; i++) {

    table.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<textarea class="date-item" onclick="selectThis(this)">' + year + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' + month : month) + '-' + (i < 10 ? '0' + i : i) + '</textarea>')

  }

}


function selectThis(textarea) {

  if (typeof selectedDate !== 'undefined')

    selectedDate.classList.remove('selected-date')

  selectedDate = textarea
  selectedDate.classList.add('selected-date')
}


function send() {

  if (typeof selectedDate === 'undefined')

    alert('No date selected')

  else

    // I have printed selected here. do whatever you want with it

    document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'Will send <b>' + selectedDate.value + '</b> to server'


  return false

}


function next() {

  if (showDate.getMonth() === 11) {

    showDate.setMonth(0)

    showDate.setFullYear(showDate.getFullYear() + 1)

  } else {

    showDate.setMonth(showDate.getMonth() + 1)

  }


  drawTable(showDate)

  return false
}


window.onload = function() {

  months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']

  // days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuseday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday']

  showDate = new Date()

  drawTable(showDate)

}
```

```css
    .date-item {
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .selected-date {
      background: #dbdbdb;
    }
```

```html
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">

  <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border-collapse="collapse" ;>

    <h1 id="date"></h1>


  </table>


  <p id="info">Select date by clicking on it</p>

  <input id="btn" type="submit" name="" onclick="return send()" value="Send">
  <input id="btn" type="submit" name="" onclick="return next()" value="Next">


</form>
```